# VUE JS - Make a page rendred only via push/replace methods from the router object not via URL bar

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My vue js app contains some error pages such as (error 400 /error 500) and i want them to be rendered only when i push them , i dont want them to be rendered when the user type the path in the URL bar

Comment: It seems you should handle it from the `.htaccess` on the server.

Comment: [Navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) might be able to help you.